# Halmos: Question about proof of Transfinite recursion theorem

Tags: elementary-set-theory, set-theory, well-orders

> If $a$ is an element of a well ordered set $W$, and if $X$ is an arbitrary set, then by a sequence of type $a$ in $X$ we shall mean a function from
> the initial segment of $a\in W$ into $X$.

> A sequence function of type $W$ in $X$ is a function $f$ whose domain consists
> of all sequences of type $a$ in $X$, for all elements $a\in W$, and whose range is
> included in $X$.

> **Transfinite recursion theorem**. If $W$ is a well ordered set, and if $f$ is
> a sequence function of type $W$ in a set $X$, then there exists a unique function $U:W\to X$ such that $U(a)=f(U^{a})$ for each $a\in W$.

Where $U^{a}=U\vert s(a)$.

> PROOF. The proof of uniqueness is an easy transfinite induction. [...] Call a subset $A$ of $W\times X$ $f$-closed if it has the following property: whenever $a\in W$ and $t$ is a sequence of type $a$ included in $A$ (that is, $(c,t(c)) \in A$ for all $c$ in the initial segment $s(a)$), then $(a,f(t))\in A$. Since $W\times X$ itself
> is $f$-closed, such sets do exist; let $U$ be the intersection of them all. Since $U$ itself
> is $f$-closed, it remains only to prove that U is a function. We are to prove, in other words, that for each $c\in W$ there exists at most one element $x\in X$ such that $(c,x)\in U$. (Explicitly: if both $(c,x)$ and $(c,y)$ belong to $C$, then $x=y$.) The proof is inductive. Let $S$ be the set of all those elements of $W$ for which it is indeed true that(c,x)\in U for at most one $x$. We shall prove that if $s(a)\in S$, then $a\in S$. To say that $s(a)\in S$ means that if $c<a$ in $W$, then there exists a unique element $x\in X$ such that $(c,x)\in U$. The correspondence $c\to x$ thereby defined is a sequence of type $a$, say $t$, and $t\subseteq U$. If $a$ does not belong to $S$, then $(a,y)\in U$ for some $y$ different from $f(t)$ Assertion: the set $U-\{(a,y)\}$
> is $f$-closed. This means that if $b\in W$ and if $r$ is a sequence of type $b$ included in $U-\{(a,y)\}$, then $(b,f(r))\in U-\{(a,y)\}$. Indeed, **if $\mathbf{b=a}$, then r must be t
> (by the uniqueness assertion of the theorem)**, [...]

How so? The uniqueness assertion is that only one such function $U$ abides the theorem, but we've yet to establish $U$ as a function at all, so it should have no bearing on this.

(Source: Halmos's *Naive Set Theory*, pp.70-71.)

Comment: There are some typos in your writeup. For example in the statement of the theorem, $U(a)=U^a$ should be $U(a)=f(U^a)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Halmos could have been clearer there. He's not referring to the uniqueness assertion about $U$ specifically, but rather the uniqueness assertion of the *theorem* generally, which he's applying to a different function.

At the specific point in the proof you highlighted, $r$ and $t$ are both functions from the well-ordered set $s(a)$ into $X$, $f$ restricts to a sequence function of type $s(a)$ in $X$, and the conditions
$$r(x)=f(r^x)\qquad\text{and}\qquad t(x)=f(t^x)$$
hold for all $x\in s(a)$ since $s(a)\subseteq S$; $r,t\subseteq U$; and $U$ is $f$-closed. So by the uniqueness assertion of the theorem applied to $r$ and $t$, it follows that $r=t$.

Answer (score 0):

The order of the proof is irrelevant, it's okay to apply what's proved first later, viz. when existence is proved.

Write $S=\{x \in W :\,U|\{x\}\text{ is unique}\}$

Suppose $s(a) \subset S$ for some $a \in W$, so $U(x)$ is uniquely determined for all $x \in s(a),i.e. U^a=U|s(a)$ is unique;

$f$ is a function, therefore $U(a)=f(U^a)$ is unique, which means $U|\{a\}$ is unique, we have then $a \in S$

By principle of transfinite induction, since $\forall a \in W( s(a) \subset S \to a \in S)$, we have $S=W$. That is, $U$ is unique for $W$.